# Changing dates in a dataframe based on the time of day?

Tags: r, date, if-statement, time

I am working on a project that defines the time of day as 7am to 7 am rather than the traditional Midnight to Midnight. I need some help changing the dates in this dataframe to match our definition of day. For example, if this dataframe says 3:54am on December 21st, I need the date to change to December 20th. However, if it says 8:59PM then the date would remain identical to what is already in the dataset.

In simpler terms, I need to change the date for all times that fall between Midnight and 7AM. Is an Ifelse statement the best way to get at this?

Sorry for the confusing language but I couldn't think of a better way of phrasing what I'm getting at with this idea.

[image]

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of [tag:r] tag when posting.

Comment: Why not just subtract 7 hours from all ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `dplyr` and `lubridate` with your `if_else` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
     mutate(Date = mdy(Date),Time = hms(Time)) %>%
     mutate(UpdatedDate = if_else(Time < hms("07:00:00"), Date - days(1), Date))
#   Country       Date       Time UpdatedDate
#1 Alamance 2015-08-11 17H 38M 0S  2015-08-11
#2 Alamance 2012-11-08 15H 52M 0S  2012-11-08
#3 Alamance 2017-11-18 20H 59M 0S  2017-11-18
#4 Alamance 2005-02-18  15H 3M 0S  2005-02-18
#5 Alamance 2008-03-23  21H 3M 0S  2008-03-23
#6 Alamance 2008-08-02         0S  2008-08-01
#7 Alamance 2007-12-21  3H 54M 0S  2007-12-20
#8 Alamance 2010-03-28     36M 0S  2010-03-27
#9 Alamance 2007-06-30 22H 17M 0S  2007-06-30
```

**Data**

```
data <- data.frame(Country = "Alamance", 
                   Date = c("8/11/2015","11/8/2012","11/18/2017","2/18/2005","3/23/2008","8/2/2008","12/21/2007","3/28/2010","6/30/2007"),
                   Time = c("17:38:00","15:52:00","20:59:00","15:03:00","21:03:00","0:00:00","3:54:00","0:36:00","22:17:00"))
```